# WebExtensionsのgetBackgroundPageでバックグラウンドの関数を呼び出せない

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-webextension

FirefoxのWebExtensionsでgetBackgroundPageを使ってbackground script上の関数を呼び出そうとすると、`Error: Permission denied to access property "f1"`というエラーが発生します

下記の例ではブラウザのポップアップにあるcheckboxがtrueの時だけ、10秒ごとにデータを取得しています。

何故、このようなエラーが起こるのでしょうか?

#### Edit: 最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードに変更

---

#### Edit 2:

chrome54ではgetBackgroundPageを使って関数がうまく実行できているようです
もしかしてFirefoxのバグなのでしょうか?

---

background-page.js:

```
function f1() {
    fetch("http://example.something.com/example").then((res) => {
        res.text().then((text) => console.log(text));
    });
}

function loop() {
    f1();
    if (getStorageValue("checked")) {
        setTimeout(loop, 10000); // setTimeoutを使って10秒ごとにデータを取得
    }
}

function getStorageValue(key) {
    let retVal;
    chrome.storage.local.get(key, (result) => {
        retVal = result[key];
    });
    return retVal;
}

loop();
```

browser_action.js

```
let bgpage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
let checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox"); // checkboxを取得
let status = document.getElementById("status");
chrome.storage.local.get("checked", (result) => {
    checkbox.checked = result.checked || true; // storageに格納したcheckboxの値を反映させる
});


checkbox.onchange = (e) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({"checked": checkbox.checked}); // checkboxの状態をstorageに格納
    if (checkbox.checked) {
            status.textContent = "ON";
            bgpage.loop(); // Error: Permission denied to access property "f1"
    }
    else {
        status.textContent = "OFF";
    }
}
```

default_popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <label class="switch">
            <span id="status">OFF</span>
            <input id="check" type="checkbox">
        </label>
        <script src="browser_action.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "My Extension",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background-page.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "*://example.something.com/example/*",
        "webRequest",
        "alarms",
        "notifications",
        "storage"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/icon-19.png",
            "38": "icons/icon-38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "my popup",
        "default_popup": "popup/default_popup.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: `getBackgroundPage()`を含むJSコードはブラウザアクション（URLの右のボタン）のポップアップで表示されるhtmlに含まれているものですか？

Comment: @packet0 ポップアップで表示されるhtmlから`script`タグで読み込んでいるものです

Comment: 例を実際の状況に合うように修正しました。

Answer (score 1):

以下のコードで手元では問題が再現しませんでした。
（`background`の関数を`popup`から直接呼ぶというやり方が正しいものなのかは解りませんが）
[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) を参考に、質問に再現可能なコードを載せて下さい。

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
* { color: white; background-color: gray; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Try Firefox WebExtension</h1>
    <p id="message_elm"></p>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage((bg_win) => {
    console.log("bg_win.url:", bg_win.url);
    bg_win.fetch_page(message_elm);
});
```

background.js

```
var url = "http://example.com/";
function fetch_page(elm){
    fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(text=>elm.textContent = text);
}
```

manifest.json

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Try_ex",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Try Firefox WebExtension",

    "icons": {
        "48": "icon_48.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "icon_48.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Try Firefox WebExtension",
            "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": ["*://example.com/*"]
}
```

Comment: 実際の状態に合わせてコードを更新しました